# How to use Docker to pull a project on host machine?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm learning about the `gitlab-ci.yml` and I started reading about [environments](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/environments) which makes me wonder, is it possible to access a folder on the host machine and perform a `git pull` command in the `deploy` stage?

```
image: php:5.6

# The folders we should cache
cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/

before_script:

# Install git, the php image doesn't have installed
- apt-get update -yqq
- apt-get install git mysql-client -yqq

# Install mysql driver
- docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

# Install composer
- curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

# Install all project dependencies
- php composer.phar install

services:
    - mysql

variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: test
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;" | mysql --user=root --password="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" --host=mysql
        - mysql --user=root --password="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" --host=mysql test < tests/assets/test.sql
        - php composer.phar tests

deploy_staging:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploying to staging server..."
    environment:
        name: staging
        url: http://staging.example.com
    only:
        - master
```

Basically all my script does is import the database file and execute the tests of the PDO service. Just a random test to learn about the CI.

Now instead of:

```
- echo "Deploying to staging server..."
```

I was wondering how I could achieve something like:

```
- cd /path/on/host/machine/to/repository
- git pull
```

If not, is there an alternative to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Yes it is possible.